# How do I convert the OpenShift MySQL 5.1 cartridge to UTF-8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, openshift

The default MySQL 5.1 cartridge apparently creates all its tables with the latin1 character set. I have an application (Review Board, a python/Django application) that has some issues unless the DB is running as UTF-8. How do I change that? I can't just edit my.cnf because it will be wiped at the next cartridge restart.

```
mysql> show variables like 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I cannot change this setting in my.cnf, because to the best of my knowledge, there exists no OpenShift environment variable to set the character encoding. How do I persistently change this (ideally in my OpenShift hooks so this will persist into future deployments) and update my existing tables to UTF-8?

Comment: As an addendum, I should note that I created this Review Board instance by using https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/reviewboard-example and then upgrading it to Review Board 2.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but not a perfect one :

In openshift installing phpMyAdmin,
Find and change server settings, the relevant character variables changed from latin1 to utf8.
Hope that helps